# chrome拡張機能で共有フォルダのファイルの読み書き

Tags: chrome-extension

chrome拡張機能を作っているのですが、共有フォルダに設置されたファイルをバックグラウンドで操作したいのですが、そう言った機能は実装できるのでしょうか？

Comment: ファイルの読み書きAPIはあるようですね。 https://developer.chrome.com/apps/fileSystem

Comment: 「共有フォルダ」とは何を指していますか？